# How can a chat application user once online again get the messages that were sent to them when they were offline

Tags: android, node.js, redis, socket.io, android-room

I'm developing an android chat app, using Node Js and redis to stock messages and user information. I'm using socket io for communication, and Room to store message in local database.  When the user is offline, I want them to receive their messages once online again. My problem is, that when user A is offline, and user B send him many messages (let's say for instance 5 messages ), when user A is online again, he only receives the first message, and the last message 4 times. Here is what I'm doing, once the user receives a message, I update the message status in Redis from "Sent" to "Delivered". In the case  when the user is offline, I stock their messages in Redis with the status of message "Sent", and once online again, I check their messages received for example from user B, if their status  is "Sent", I deliver it to the user, and then it will be updted to "Delivered", as shown in the code below:

```
      //On this event, we update the socket ID of the sender in Redis so they can 
receive private messages from their contacts
socket.on('sender', (sender, destinat) =>{
tempId = socket.id;
senderId = sender;
users[sender] = sender;
users [destinat] = destinat;

//We also update the user status: online
client.hset(senderId, 'lastSeen', 'Now', function(reply){
           console.log( senderId + reply);
     });

//Stocking to the user socket id 
client.hset(users[sender], 'tempId', tempId, function(){
           console.log("Welcome " + sender);
            console.log("Welcome " + tempId);
  });


 //Getting all the messages of the sender from users

 //If the sender has any messages that hasn't received yet, they'll be sent 
  here
 //the id of each message is compsed of two parts: the phone number of the 
 receiver, and the id of  the message itself 
 (receiverPhoneNumber:idMessage)
  client.keys(users [sender] + ':*', function(err, results) {

      results.forEach(function(key) {


         client.hgetall(key, function(err, reply){

             if(err)
             console.log(err);
             else if(reply){

      //Compare the message status: if not sent, deliver it to receiver once online

                  if('Sent'.localeCompare(reply.status) == 0 && users 
[destinat].localeCompare(reply.fromUser)  == 0) {

                   io.to(tempId).emit('message', reply);


              }  

        }


    });


 });


 });

 });
```

After receiving messages from the server, I use Async to store them in Room Database and then display them to the user, as shown in the following code

And here is the AsyncTask Class:

```
class AddMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {


        //Creating a user account
        m = new Message();
        m.setContent( message );
        m.setTime( time );
        m.setUrl( url );
        m.setStatus( status );
        m.setFromUser( fromUser );
        m.setToUser( toUser );
        m.setUsername( receiver.getUsername() );
        //adding to database
        DatabaseClient.getInstance(getContext()).getAppDatabase()
                .messageDao()
                .insert(m);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Toast.makeText( getContext(), "Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();



    }
}
```

I've checked that messages are received from the server to the android app correctly (by re-sending the messages again to the server once delivered to the app). I believe the problem has something to do with AsyncTask, but I just can't figure it out, any help is greatly appreciated, thank you so much.

```
 //When receving a message
    socket.on("message", new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            if(getActivity() != null){
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                        try {
                            //extract data from fired event


                            idMessage = data.getString( "idMessage" );
                            message = data.getString("message");
                            fromUser = data.getString( "fromUser" );
                            toUser = data.getString( "toUser" );
                            time = data.getString( "time" );
                            status = data.getString( "status" );
                            url = data.getString( "url" );             
                             //Here we call asyncTask to Add it to Database
                            addMessage = new AddMessage();
                            addMessage.execute(  );

                            //We emit this event to update the status of 
                            the message to delivered
                            socket.emit( "sent", idMessage, userID );


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by switching to `RxJava` instead of `AsyncTask`. The problem had something to do with AsyncTask as it sometimes influnces the chain of data, which is not the case with `RxJava`, as mentioned in [this link](http://code.hootsuite.com/asynchronous-android-programming-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/) : "Another issue with AsyncTasks is if you have more than one running at once. You have no guarantee what order they’ll complete in, resulting in complex logic to check when all the tasks have completed. Even worse is the assumption that one will finish before the other, until you hit an edge case that makes the first call slower, which makes them complete in the wrong order and undesired results."